# JS autoscroll tweaking

Tags: javascript, scroll, autoscroll

I have this 3rd party horizontal autoscrolling script that is scrolling number sequences for students to practice counting, and I have successfully cobbled together a couple text links that change the sequence of numbers, which is already pushing the limits of my JS abilities. I want to accomplish/address 3 things:

1. A basic problem is the new numbers are activated wherever the scrolling happens to be, without interrupting the scrolling, and if it's stopped (because the initial scrolling event has finished) then that's it, there's nothing. I need the scrolling to be reset and re-activated whenever one of these text links is clicked to change the numbers. This is the most important thing I need to address.
2. As you can see I have two separate scripts to accomodate the two changes that are invoked. I don't understand how to combine the functions.
3. I would very much like to create a set of +/- buttons that adjust the speed. The relevant code that needs to be affected is that number 17 at the end of the main script.

Many thanks and much appreciated! Here's the code, it's streamlined and fundamentally works well.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
        body {
            padding: 40px;
            font-size: 30px;
            line-height: 2em;
        }
        .container {
            width: 150px;
            overflow-x: scroll;
            white-space: nowrap;
            word-spacing: 30px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
    
    <body>
        <div class="container" id="flavoursContainer">
            <div id="the-numbers">1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15</div>
        </div>
        <div onclick="myFunction()">Change</div>
        <div onclick="test()">Change again</div>
        
        <script>
    const flavoursContainer = document.getElementById("flavoursContainer")
const flavoursScrollWidth = flavoursContainer.scrollWidth

window.addEventListener("load", () => {
  self.setInterval(() => {
    if (flavoursContainer.scrollLeft !== flavoursScrollWidth) {
      flavoursContainer.scrollTo(flavoursContainer.scrollLeft + 1, 0);
    }
  }, 17);
})
        </script>
        <script>
        function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("the-numbers").innerHTML = "25 50 75 100 125 150 175 200";                
}
        </script>
        <script>
        function test() {
  document.getElementById("the-numbers").innerHTML = "11 21 31 41 51 61 71 81 91 101";              
}
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just reset the scrollLeft value to 0 when you call your functions!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <style>
      body {
        padding: 40px;
        font-size: 30px;
        line-height: 2em;
      }
      .container {
        width: 150px;
        overflow-x: scroll;
        white-space: nowrap;
        word-spacing: 30px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container" id="flavoursContainer">
      <div id="the-numbers">1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15</div>
    </div>
    <div onclick="myFunction()">Change</div>
    <div onclick="test()">Change again</div>

    <script>
      const flavoursContainer = document.getElementById("flavoursContainer");
      const flavoursScrollWidth = flavoursContainer.scrollWidth;

      window.addEventListener("load", () => {
        self.setInterval(() => {
          if (flavoursContainer.scrollLeft !== flavoursScrollWidth) {
            flavoursContainer.scrollTo(flavoursContainer.scrollLeft + 1, 0);
          }
        }, 17);
      });

      function myFunction() {
        flavoursContainer.scrollLeft = 0;
        document.getElementById("the-numbers").innerHTML =
          "25 50 75 100 125 150 175 200";
      }

      function test() {
        flavoursContainer.scrollLeft = 0;
        document.getElementById("the-numbers").innerHTML =
          "11 21 31 41 51 61 71 81 91 101";
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Also, if you want to have buttons adjusting the scroll speed, set a variable for the scroll speed and adjust it's value when you click a button.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <style>
      body {
        padding: 40px;
        font-size: 30px;
        line-height: 2em;
      }
      .container {
        width: 150px;
        overflow-x: scroll;
        white-space: nowrap;
        word-spacing: 30px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container" id="flavoursContainer">
      <div id="the-numbers">1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15</div>
    </div>
    <div onclick="myFunction()">Change</div>
    <div onclick="test()">Change again</div>
    <button onclick="decreaseSpeed()">-</button>
    <button onclick="increaseSpeed()">+</button>

    <script>
      const flavoursContainer = document.getElementById("flavoursContainer");
      const flavoursScrollWidth = flavoursContainer.scrollWidth;
      let speed = 1;

      window.addEventListener("load", () => {
        self.setInterval(() => {
          if (flavoursContainer.scrollLeft !== flavoursScrollWidth) {
            flavoursContainer.scrollTo(flavoursContainer.scrollLeft + speed, 0);
          }
        }, 17);
      });

      function myFunction() {
        flavoursContainer.scrollLeft = 0;
        document.getElementById("the-numbers").innerHTML =
          "25 50 75 100 125 150 175 200";
      }

      function test() {
        flavoursContainer.scrollLeft = 0;
        document.getElementById("the-numbers").innerHTML =
          "11 21 31 41 51 61 71 81 91 101";
      }

      function increaseSpeed() {
        speed++;
      }
      function decreaseSpeed() {
        if (speed > 1) {
          speed--;
        }
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks Robert, this addresses points 1 & 2 successfully. If anyone is able to help with the speed control it'd be much appreciated.

Comment: I've included the scroll speed feature in my answer as well.

Comment: Fantastic, greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi Robert, if I could ask one more thing, I would like to know how to make this scroll vertically, in addition to horizontally. Thanks so much.